# How to count instances of a string occurring in an array of cells

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that tracks where consumers are referred to.  To record individual referrals, users select places from a drop down list.  This list then populates a cell, with values separated by commas.

On a separate sheet, I need to count the number of referrals for each referral type.  So I need to count the # of times DHHS shows up in the array, for example.  I've attempted to do this using the following formula:

=SUM(LEN(*range*))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(*range*,"*string*",""))/LEN("*string*")

This is working fine for single word strings, but is not working for multiple word strings like "CHIP Water Inquiry".  Any ideas why, and what I can do about it?

Comment: Have you tried applying it as an array formula with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two minor corrections, as you are breathtakingly close in your formula. Add a second SUM formula, tally the subtracted length and then house the two subtracted  sections within parentheses as you see in the posted formula. As Boris said, Ctrl + Shift + Enter it, as you probably already know. F1 is assumed to hold your "string" that you wish to count.

=(SUM(LEN(range))-SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,F1,""))))/LEN(F1)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there any way to use this formula for ranges involving multiple blocks of cells?  For example:

=(SUM(LEN(range1, range2,...))-SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range, range2,...,F1,""))))/LEN(F1)

I need to be scanning multiple arrays located in several different ranges.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. It's not super elegant but I just added all the functions together for the ranges I needed, one range per function.  Thanks again